# select2 and remote data: pre-set value and text avoiding server round-trip

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I am generating my HTML tags server-side (asp.net mvc4).
I would like to pre-set the value and the description of my HIDDEN field avoiding the ajax call to fetch the data in the `initSelection` function.

I've seen someone setting the values using javascript:

```
$("#select2Test").select2('data', { id: 20832, text: 'LONDON' })
```

but still it would require me extra-code to achieve something that has been already streamed from the server in a viewmodel.

I've come up with something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="select2Test" name="select2Test" value="20832" data-option="LONDON" />
```

I've used an HTML5 data attribute `data-option` with the description of my lookup and I've implemented the initSelection function so that I can read the value of my field and it's data attribute:

```
initSelection: function (item, callback) {
   var id = item.val();
   var text = item.data('option');
   var data = { id: id, text: text };
   callback(data);
},
```

I've seen that initSelection is called only when the hidden field has a value set.
Everything seems to work properly.

Are there any better options?

Comment: What are you doing exactly in the callback? Wouldn't it be better to load that data as well upon loading the page?

Comment: @Kenneth: I've updated my question. There's the full code there. The page is loaded already. My controller returns a view and a viewmodel with the entire dataset.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`data-option` combined with a custom `initSelection` did the trick.

```
    $("#lookup_id").select2({
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        multiple: false,
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: urlFetchCity,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            data: function (term, page) { return { city: term }; },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return {
                    return {results: data};
                };
            }
        },
        initSelection: function (item, callback) {
            var id = item.val();
            var text = item.data('option');
            var data = { id: id, text: text };
            callback(data);
        },
        formatResult: function (item) { return ('<div>' + item.id + ' - ' + item.text + '</div>'); },
        formatSelection: function (item) { return (item.text); },
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
    });
```

for those who are interested I've created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Leftyx/MvcWithSelect2) where you can find an **ASP.NET MVC4** project in which I've added an html helper to create a **select2** tags with all the features for client-side validation.